# Failed to compile in react js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, node-modules, redux-saga

I am new to react JS and I am developing a website for my client in react JS and Redux Saga. I have installed all the required modules for the project but it still gives me an error.
I have tried downgrading the versions too but still am getting the same error.
This same project runs on my colleague's laptop who is helping me with this project.

```js
 This is my package.json file

{
    "name": "typescript-redux-starter-kit",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/jest": "^20.0.8",
        "@types/node": "^8.0.26",
        "@types/qs": "^6.5.0",
        "@types/react": "^16.0.5",
        "@types/react-dom": "^15.5.4",
        "@types/react-redux": "^5.0.7",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.0.7",
        "@types/react-router-redux": "^5.0.8",
        "app-root-path": "^2.0.1",
        "autoprefixer": "7.1.1",
        "axios": "^0.16.2",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
        "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
        "chalk": "1.1.3",
        "cli-highlight": "1.1.4",
        "css-loader": "0.28.4",
        "dotenv": "4.0.0",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
        "file-loader": "0.11.2",
        "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
        "history": "^4.7.2",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "2.28.0",
        "install": "^0.10.1",
        "jest": "20.0.3",
        "moment": "^2.18.1",
        "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
        "npm": "^5.4.1",
        "object-assign": "4.1.1",
        "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.0.0",
        "postcss-loader": "2.0.5",
        "promise": "7.1.1",
        "qs": "^6.5.1",
        "react": "^15.6.2",
        "react-dev-utils": "^3.0.1",
        "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
        "react-error-overlay": "^1.0.8",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
        "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
        "reactstrap": "^6.5.0",
        "redux": "^3.7.2",
        "redux-saga": "^0.15.6",
        "redux-saga-router": "^2.1.1",
        "reselect": "^3.0.1",
        "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
        "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
        "style-loader": "0.18.2",
        "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.3",
        "ts-jest": "^20.0.7",
        "ts-loader": "^2.2.1",
        "tslint": "^5.2.0",
        "tslint-loader": "^3.5.3",
        "tslint-react": "^3.0.0",
        "typescript": "~2.4.0",
        "url-loader": "0.5.8",
        "webpack": "2.6.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "2.5.0",
        "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.1.0",
        "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3",
        "wildstring": "^1.0.9"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node scripts/start.js",
        "build": "node scripts/build.js",
        "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
    },
    "jest": {
        "mapCoverage": true,
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
        ],
        "setupFiles": [
            "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
        ],
        "modulePaths": [
            "src",
            "src/modules"
        ],
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "web.ts",
            "ts",
            "web.tsx",
            "tsx",
            "web.js",
            "js",
            "web.jsx",
            "jsx",
            "json"
        ],
        "testMatch": [
            "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.ts?(x)",
            "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).ts?(x)"
        ],
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "testURL": "http://localhost",
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
            "^.+\\.tsx?$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/typescriptTransform.js",
            "^(?!.*\\.(css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
        },
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$"
        ],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
            "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
        },
        "globals": {
            "ts-jest": {
                "tsConfigFile": "/Users/robby.emmert/CQL/cql/typescript-redux-starter-kit/tsconfig.test.json"
            }
        }
    },
    "babel": {
        "presets": [
            "react-app"
        ]
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/enzyme": "^2.8.8",
        "@types/reactstrap": "^6.4.2",
        "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
        "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.0.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "^15.6.1"
    }
}
```

This is my ts.json file

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*",
        "src/modules/*",
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

This is the error that is shown when I run the project:

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade TypeScript to version 2.8 or newer, since `@types/react-router` depends on the `Exclude` type alias that was added in TypeScript 2.8.  (Note that the comment at the top of the `node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts` file specifies the minimum required TypeScript version.)  I'd suggest upgrading TypeScript to the latest stable version (currently 3.1.3) since improvements are made in every version.

Comment: I have already updated all the modules to the latest versions in my PC

Comment: How are you running the project?  `npm run start`?  If so, what is in `scripts/start.js`?  If you run `node_modules/.bin/tsc --version`, what do you see?